# Sort a list of tuples in consecutive order

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I want to sort a list of tuples in a **consecutive order**, so the first element of each tuple is equal to the last element of the previous one.

For example:

```
input = [(10, 7), (4, 9), (13, 4), (7, 13), (9, 10)]
output = [(10, 7), (7, 13), (13, 4), (4, 9), (9, 10)]
```

I have developed a search like this:

```
output=[]
given = [(10, 7), (4, 9), (13, 4), (7, 13), (9, 10)]
t = given[0][0]
for i in range(len(given)):
      # search tuples starting with element t
      output += [e for e in given if e[0] == t]
      t = output[-1][-1] # Get the next element to search

print(output)
```

Is there a pythonic way to achieve such order?
And a way to do it "in-place" (with only a list)?

In my problem, the input can be reordered in a circular way using all the tuples, so it is not important the first element chosen.

Comment: what if one tuple is not match with any of the others?

Comment: Also, are the pairings unique, or must you handle backtracking if you pair them up incorrectly the first try?

Comment: I don't think either of the terms *sort* or *consecutive* apply to this problem.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Ten, how would you expose this problem?

Comment: `order a list` sounds to me already better than `sort a list` in this context.

Still looking for a better word. but `sort` is definitely misleading as it suggest, that a sorting algorithm can be used, which means that by just looking at two entries of the list you know which one is smaller than the other one

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming your tuples in the `list` will be circular, you may use `dict` to achieve it within complexity of *O(n)* as:

```
input = [(10, 7), (4, 9), (13, 4), (7, 13), (9, 10)]
input_dict = dict(input)  # Convert list of `tuples` to dict

elem = input[0][0]  # start point in the new list

new_list = []  # List of tuples for holding the values in required order

for _ in range(len(input)):
    new_list.append((elem, input_dict[elem]))
    elem = input_dict[elem]
    if elem not in input_dict:
        # Raise exception in case list of tuples is not circular
        raise Exception('key {} not found in dict'.format(elem))
```

Final value hold by `new_list` will be:

```
>>> new_list
[(10, 7), (7, 13), (13, 4), (4, 9), (9, 10)]
```

Comment: I like your 'dict(input)' conversion proposal, it enhances the speed for long input arrays.

Comment: I will be glad to know the reason of down-vote. May be I can improve it :)

Comment: Perhaps it was because a `KeyError` exception would be raised `if elem not in input_dict` in the line just above your check. You should probably use a `try:\n elem = ... m]\n except KeyError:\n raise KeyError(...` instead.

Comment: That will never happen as per the logic in the code.Before raising the `KeyError`, code's `Exception` will be raised which is a custom exception I am using which OP may modify as per his/her requirement. Reason: Loop starts with known `key` and before assigning the next key, I check for the presence in the keys of dict

Answer (score 5):

if you are not afraid to waste some memory you could create a dictionary `start_dict` containing the start integers as keys and the tuples as values and do something like this:

```
tpl = [(10, 7), (4, 9), (13, 4), (7, 13), (9, 10)]
start_dict = {item[0]: item for item in tpl}

start = tpl[0][0]
res = []
while start_dict:
    item = start_dict[start]
    del start_dict[start]
    res.append(item)
    start = item[-1]

print(res)
```

if two tuples start with the same number you will lose one of them... if not all the start numbers are used the loop will not terminate.

but maybe this is something to build on.

Comment: Why do you bother to delete the element start_dict[start] from the dictionary?

Comment: Also, I prefer the start = item[-1], because the solution still would work with tuples with more than 2 elements. Even variable tuple lengths as [ (1,2), (7, 3, 1), (2, 4, 6, 7) ]

Comment: @user3715819: the loop (as it is now) terminates when `start_dict` is empty; that's why i bother deleting from it. but yes: there is much room for improvement!

Answer (score 2):

Actually there're many questions about what you intend to have as an output and what if the input list has invalid structure to do what you need.

Assuming you have an input of pairs where each number is included twice only. So we can consider such input as a graph where numbers are nodes and each pair is an edge. And as far as I understand your question you suppose that this graph is cyclic and looks like this:

```
10 - 7 - 13 - 4 - 9 - 10 (same 10 as at the beginning)
```

This shows you that you can reduce the list to store the graph to `[10, 7, 13, 4, 9]`. And here is the script that sorts the input list:

```
# input
input = [(10, 7), (4, 9), (13, 4), (7, 13), (9, 10)]

# sorting and archiving
first = input[0][0]
last = input[0][1]
output_in_place = [first, last]

while last != first:
    for item in input:
        if item[0] == last:
            last = item[1]
            if last != first:
                output_in_place.append(last)

print(output_in_place)

# output
output = []
for i in range(len(output_in_place) - 1):
    output.append((output_in_place[i], output_in_place[i+1]))
output.append((output_in_place[-1], output_in_place[0]))

print(output)
```

Answer (score 2):

I would first create a dictionary of the form

```
{first_value: [list of tuples with that first value], ...}
```

Then work from there:

```
from collections import defaultdict

chosen_tuples = input[:1]  # Start from the first

first_values = defaultdict()
for tup in input[1:]:
    first_values[tup[0]].append(tup)

while first_values:  # Loop will end when all lists are removed
    value = chosen_tuples[-1][1]  # Second item of last tuple
    tuples_with_that_value = first_values[value]
    chosen_tuples.append(tuples_with_that_value.pop())
    if not chosen_with_that_value:
        del first_values[value]  # List empty, remove it
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
input = [(10, 7), (4, 9), (13, 4), (7, 13), (9, 10)]

output = [input[0]]  # output contains the first element of input
temp = input[1:]  # temp contains the rest of elements in input

while temp:
    item = [i for i in temp if i[0] == output[-1][1]].pop()  # We compare each element with output[-1]
    output.append(item)  # We add the right item to output
    temp.remove(item)  # We remove each handled element from temp
```

**Output:**

```
>>> output
[(10, 7), (7, 13), (13, 4), (4, 9), (9, 10)]
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a (less efficient than the dictionary version) variant where the list is changed in-place:

```
tpl = [(10, 7), (4, 9), (13, 4), (7, 13), (9, 10)]

for i in range(1, len(tpl)-1):   # iterate over the indices of the list
    item = tpl[i]
    for j, next_item in enumerate(tpl[i+1:]):  # find the next item 
                                               # in the remaining list
        if next_item[0] == item[1]:
            next_index = i + j
            break
    tpl[i], tpl[next_index] = tpl[next_index], tpl[i]  # now swap the items
```

here is a more efficient version of the same idea:

```
tpl = [(10, 7), (4, 9), (13, 4), (7, 13), (9, 10)]
start_index = {item[0]: i for i, item in enumerate(tpl)}

item = tpl[0]
next_index = start_index[item[-1]]
for i in range(1, len(tpl)-1):
    tpl[i], tpl[next_index] = tpl[next_index], tpl[i]
    # need to update the start indices:
    start_index[tpl[next_index][0]] = next_index
    start_index[tpl[i][0]] = i
    next_index = start_index[tpl[i][-1]]
print(tpl)
```

the list is changed in-place; the dictionary only contains the starting values of the tuples and their index in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a robust solution using the `sorted` function and a custom key function:

```
input = [(10, 7), (4, 9), (13, 4), (7, 13), (9, 10)]

def consec_sort(lst):
    def key(x):
        nonlocal index
        if index <= lower_index:
            index += 1
            return -1
        return abs(x[0] - lst[index - 1][1])
    for lower_index in range(len(lst) - 2):
        index = 0
        lst = sorted(lst, key=key)
    return lst

output = consec_sort(input)
print(output)
```

The original list is not modified. Note that `sorted` is called 3 times for your `input` list of length 5. In each call, one additional tuple is placed correctly. The first tuple keeps it original position.

I have used the `nonlocal` keyword, meaning that this code is for Python 3 only (one could use `global` instead to make it legal Python 2 code).

Answer (score 0):

My two cents:

```
def match_tuples(input):
    # making a copy to not mess up with the original one
    tuples = input[:]          # [(10,7), (4,9), (13, 4), (7, 13), (9, 10)]
    last_elem = tuples.pop(0)  # (10,7)

    # { "first tuple's element": "index in list"}
    indexes = {tup[0]: i for i, tup in enumerate(tuples)} # {9: 3, 4: 0, 13: 1, 7: 2}

    yield last_elem  # yields de firts element

    for i in range(len(tuples)):
        # get where in the list is the tuple which first element match the last element in the last tuple
        list_index = indexes.get(last_elem[1])
        last_elem = tuples[list_index] # just get that tuple
        yield last_elem
```

**Output**:

```
input = [(10,7), (4,9), (13, 4), (7, 13), (9, 10)]
print(list(match_tuples(input)))
# output: [(10, 7), (7, 13), (13, 4), (4, 9), (9, 10)]
```

Answer (score 0):

To get a `O(n)` algorithm one needs to make sure that one doesn't do a double-loop over the array. One way to do this is by keeping already processed values in some sort of lookup-table (a `dict` would be a good choice).

For example something like this (I hope the inline comments explain the functionality well). This modifies the list in-place and should avoid unnecessary (even implicit) looping over the list:

```
inp = [(10, 7), (4, 9), (13, 4), (7, 13), (9, 10)]

# A dictionary containing processed elements, first element is
# the key and the value represents the tuple. This is used to
# avoid the double loop
seen = {}

# The second value of the first tuple. This must match the first
# item of the next tuple
current = inp[0][1]

# Iteration to insert the next element
for insert_idx in range(1, len(inp)):
    # print('insert', insert_idx, seen)
    # If the next value was already found no need to search, just
    # pop it from the seen dictionary and continue with the next loop
    if current in seen:
        item = seen.pop(current)
        inp[insert_idx] = item
        current = item[1]
        continue

    # Search the list until the next value is found saving all
    # other items in the dictionary so we avoid to do unnecessary iterations
    # over the list.
    for search_idx in range(insert_idx, len(inp)):
        # print('search', search_idx, inp[search_idx])
        item = inp[search_idx]
        first, second = item
        if first == current:
            # Found the next tuple, break out of the inner loop!
            inp[insert_idx] = item
            current = second
            break
        else:
            seen[first] = item
```