# Longest cycle of key-value pairs in a dictionary without recursion

Tags: python, dictionary

I've a question regarding a dictionaries. I would like to know how to solve this without using recursive functions (since that is a requirement). 
The code creates a random dictionary with the names in the nameslist connected to each other. I know what the code should do, but not how to do this.

I need the starting key, which I succesfully extract (probably in an incorrect/ugly manner). Then the code should loop the entire cycle as shown in the quote at the bottom of my code, untill the starting key has been found again as a value. The loop should then end and return the length of this cycle.

The code below is what I managed to come up with, even though it is wrong. 
I would prefer an answer *without* recursive functions as said before.

```
from random import seed, choice
import time
seed(0)
nameslist = [ "Liam", "Emma", "Noah", "Olivia", ]


# Creates random couples dictionary from a list
def create_dictionary(nlist):
    dict = {}
    nlistcopy = nlist[:]
    for item in nlist:
        dict[item] = choice(nlistcopy)
        nlistcopy.remove(dict[item])
    return dict

# Generates the longest cycle in the couples dictionary, however, the code does not seem to work.

def longest_cycle(dict):
    longest = 0
    for each in dict:
        start = dict[each]
        break
    each = 0
    while each != start :
        for each in dict:
            each = dict[each]
            print(each)
            longest += 1
        time.sleep(5)


namesdict = create_dictionary(nameslist)
print(longest_cycle(namesdict))

# Dictionary = {'Liam': 'Olivia', 'Noah': 'Liam', 'Olivia': 'Noah', 'Emma': 'Emma'}
# Liam --> Olivia --> Noah --> Liam (longest cycle = 3)!
```

The eventual list of names will contain much more names, this shorter version is just for testing purposes. The sleeping time is implemented to prevent the infinite loop from crashing my notebook (I'm using Jupyter notebook to tackle the issue). Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort a list of tuples in consecutive order](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41221428/sort-a-list-of-tuples-in-consecutive-order)

Comment: I don't think so, this looks more like a DFS

Comment: You need to find the list of consecutive dict starting from each key similar to the dupe mentioned above. Map the path for each key with the counter. At the end you can extract the path based on counter

Comment: @Menno Van Dijk you should have a look at my answer, there is a couple things you could use in the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there is a better solution but anyway, this is very simple and does not use any recursive function:

```
dict = {'Liam': 'Olivia', 'Noah': 'Liam', 'Olivia': 'Noah', 'Emma': 'Emma'}

result = 0
longest = 1 # longest_cycle of a key, always == 1 at first

for key in dict.keys():
    dest = key
    key = dict[key]
    while dest != key:
        key = dict[key]
        longest += 1
    if longest > result:
        result = longest
    longest = 0

print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Firs thing avoid naming `dict` which is a reserved word just like `list`, second let's simplify the code:

```
import random

def create_names_dict(names_list):
    names_list_random = names_list[:]
    random.shuffle(names_list_random)
    return {k:v for k,v in zip(names_list, names_list_random)}
```

Next step:

```
def longest_cycle(names_list, names_dict):
    start = names_list[0]
    key = start
    value = names_dict[start]
    longest = [start]
    while start != value:
        longest.append(value)
        key, value = value, names_dict[value]
    longest.append(value)
    print('%s (longest cycle: %d)' % (' --> '.join(longest), len(longest) - 1))
```

Test:

```
>>> names_list = [ "Liam", "Emma", "Noah", "Olivia", ]
>>> names_dict = create_names_dict(names_list)
>>> names_dict
{'Noah': 'Noah', 'Liam': 'Emma', 'Olivia': 'Liam', 'Emma': 'Olivia'}
>>> longest_cycle(names_list, names_dict)
Liam --> Emma --> Olivia --> Liam (longest cycle: 3)
```

Cheers!